# How to use CollisionBehavior properly to bring items to collide with each other

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3, collision

Probably an easy one for you.

I simply want to use the collisionMode the right way.  My code seems ok (no bug), but items collide only with the boundaries of the view. Not with each other.

I'm wondering if "translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary" would be overwriting the collisionMode.

Maybe I should use the "addBoundary(withIdentifier:NSCopying, from: CGPoint, to:CGPoint)" method instead of "translateReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary"  but didn't find how to implement the NSCopying class.

Below my code for details.

Thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var tests:[String] = ["test1","test2","test3","test4","test5","test6","test7","test8","test9","test10","test11"]

var label:UILabel!
var color:UIColor!

var dynamicBehavior:UIDynamicBehavior!
var collisionBehavior:UICollisionBehavior!

var animatorArray = [UIDynamicAnimator]()


var countLabel = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let size:CGFloat = 50.0
    var positionX:CGFloat = 60.0
    var positionY:CGFloat = 100.0


    for test in tests {
    label = UILabel(frame:CGRect(x: positionX, y: positionY, width: size, height: size))
    label.center = CGPoint(x: positionX, y: positionY)
    label.layer.cornerRadius = size * 0.5
    label.layer.masksToBounds = true
    label.backgroundColor = color
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    label.text = test
    self.view.addSubview(label)
    countLabel = countLabel + 1

        if countLabel == 4 || countLabel == 8 {
            positionX = positionX - 140
            positionY = positionY + 100 }
        else { positionX = positionX + 60}

    for (i,_) in tests.enumerated() {

        let gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [label])
        let direction = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 1.0)
        gravity.gravityDirection = direction

        let bounce = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [label])
        bounce.elasticity = 1.0

        let collisions = UICollisionBehavior(items: [label])
        collisions.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true
        collisions.collisionMode = UICollisionBehaviorMode.everything

    animatorArray.append(UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view))
    animatorArray[i].addBehavior(bounce)
    animatorArray[i].addBehavior(collisions)
    animatorArray[i].addBehavior(gravity)
    }
}

}
}
```

Comment: Dude. NSCopying is just a string. `coll.addBoundary(withIdentifier: "bottom" as NSString, from:p1, to:p2)`

Comment: thank you matt.  Yes, indeed it was easy.  I was searching to far.

Comment: No problem! And I see keithbhunter has answered your actual question correctly, so you should be good to go. (You should accept his answer: he's perfectly right about the construction of your loop.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your labels is being added to a separate instance of `UIDynamicAnimator` with separate instances of all the behaviors in your for-loop. You can make just one property of the animator and each of your behaviors and add each of your labels to the same animator and behaviors. This way the animator is in charge of ALL of the labels, instead of just one.

Comment: I see what you mean keithbhunter.  I will try to figure out how to do it.  (I'm new to object oriented programming).  Thank you for the advice.